# Typo3 select filled with childs category from sys_category

Tags: typo3, typo3-tca

I'm writing a TCA to define a form, and I need to fill the select with the childs categories from sys_category table.

```
'category' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:hebo_ideas/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:hk_ideas_idea.category',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'foreign_table' => 'sys_category',
                'foreign_table_where' => ' AND sys_category.sys_language_uid IN (-1, 0) ORDER BY sys_category.sorting ASC',
                'MM' => 'sys_category_record_mm',
                'size' => 10
            ],
         ],
```

I understand that I have to use `foreign_table_where` but I don't know what parameter from TYPO3 core database should I use to filter this categories by parent. Or may be my approach is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add categories to your table, you should use `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::makeCategorizable()`. Thats the easiest way. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Categories/Index.html#making-a-table-categorizable) for details.